# Paho python client connection failure to HiveMQ with connection return code 7

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, hivemq

I have been testing a python client (Paho) with my local MQTT server (windows 10). It is working fine with passwords and TLS as well.

My Paho python client successfully connects to HiveMQ public mosquito broker using port 1883 without any issues as well!

But when I tried to connect to my hiveMQ cloud broker using port 8883, it fails to connect to the broker with return code 7. According to my understanding MQTT Connection Return Codes are only defined up to 5, can someone explain what causes this error?

I successfully connected to the cloud broker using my Linux mosquito broker using the following command

```
mosquitto_sub -h f86f3a7384644b569094607fbe400e2e.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud -p 8883 -u manoj2 -P my_PASSWORD -t my/test/topic
```

But when I tried the same command on the windows 10 mosquito broker it returns the following error

```
Error: protocol error
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74778256/edit) the question to show the code you are using to setup the connection. Also which broker where you running locally on your windows machine?

Comment: You can fix `mosquitto_sub` on windows by grabbing the [`isrgrootx1` cert](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem) and using that i.e. `mosquitto_sub -h f86f3a7384644b569094607fbe400e2e.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud -p 8883 -u manoj2 -P my_PASSWORD -t my/test/topic --cafile isrgrootx1.pem` - I'm assuming this is related [to this](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/openssl-client-compatibility-changes-for-let-s-encrypt-certificates/143816) but cannot be sure (Mosquitto does not appear to be using the correct CA cert from the windows cert store).

Comment: You need to explictliy tell `mosquitto_sub` that it's a TLS connection, just passing the port number will not work. `--tls-use-os-certs` will use the Windows cert store or using `--cafile` or `--capath` enables TLS mode

Comment: @hardillb `mosquitto_sub` assumes tls if the port is 8883 (from the man "if the -p 8883 option is used then the OS provided certificates..."). The command above works for me (with my hivemq account), I got the same error as the op when using `tls-use-os-certs`.

Comment: @Brits must be a recent change (I wish the man page had "add in 2.0.x" in it... (will poke Roger later)

Comment: @hardillb@Brits Thanks for the comments and suggestions, I managed to resolve the problem by adding the TLS CA certificate to the code.  (--cafile isrgrootx1.pem). I am curious why it worked in Linux without the certificate but did not work in windows. (both use same version (v2.X) Mosquitto broker.